# How do I return data in my MVC application based on Ids passed in using an array to a Kendo Grid?

Tags: javascript, linq, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I want to pass an array of ids to my controller and return only the records with matching ids to my Kendo Grid.

Here is what I have so far, my javascript function and a basic array.

```
var cars = [1,2,3];
function myParams() {
    return {
        array: cars
    }
}
```

Here is my controller.

```
private UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();

public ActionResult GetTabCars(int[] array, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var car = unitOfWork.CarRepository.Get().Where(u => array.Any(x => x == u.Id));
        var result = car.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);        
}
```

My unit of work is a generic repository.  Here is the `Get` metod from `GenericRepository.cs`

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "")
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                return orderBy(query).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return query.ToList();
            }
        }
```

Because the Ids are of type `int` I can't use `.Contains`.  Although my controller method doesn't report any errors, there is no data in my grid.  Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Can you post `unitofwork` and `CarRepository` snippet just to know wt you are using?

Comment: Thanks @Sumitraj I've updated my question to show my unit of work, specifically the `Get` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue with your code is

```
var car = unitOfWork.CarRepository.Get().Where(u => array.Any(x => x == u.Id));
```

You are querying a list(`unitOfWork.CarRepository.Get()`) which will always result in count 0 as arguments haven't been passed),so it won't ever give you result.

I am also not sure what expression should be passed but there is a workaround. Probably someone will provide you a better answer but till den you might use it.

In your repository **there must be a method to fetch single record** say `FindSingleOrDefault()`. If `FindSingleOrDefault()` isn't there you can paste this code

```
public TEntity FindSingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return _context.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(predicate);
        }
```

so you can use this.

```
List<Car> cars=new List<Car>();
foreach(var id in array)
{
  cars.Add(unitOfWork.CarRepository.FindSingleOrDefault(x=>x.id==id));
}
```

`Cars` will contain all the car records with matching id.

**If it was not repository pattern** then simple linq query would have been like

```
var cars = (from id in array
            join car in dbSet.Cars
            on id equals car.id
            select car).ToList();
```

Let me know if you face issue applying this answer.

Comment: Thank you for this anwer, I got it to work by integrating it with my repository as you describe in the first instance.